# Eigen vect Armadillo c++

Tags: c++, armadillo, eigenvector

I am a beginner with Armadillo, and I have some questions about calculation of eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

I started with a little code, but I got an error message and I didn't understand what to do excatly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    cx_mat Y = randu<cx_mat>(5,5);
    cout << "Y:\n" << Y << endl;

    cx_vec eigval;
    cx_mat eigvec;
    eig_gen(eigval, eigvec, Y);

    cout << "eigenval:\n" << eigval << endl;
    cout << "eigenvect:\n" << eigvec << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the error message is the following : 
C:\Users\Desktop\armadillo-9.200.\include\armadillo_bits\wrapper_lapack.hpp|168|undefined reference to `zgeev_'

I will appreciate any help

Thank you

Comment: Link with lapack (the config probably has ARMA_USE_LAPACK?)